# Database routing by hostname

Tags: python, django

I want to route the specific request on a host to different database for example My default app is running on `www.example.com` if user requests on `www.sub.example.com` I want to use a different database. I can get the hostname by `request.META['HOST']` and I tried something like this

```
class MultipleDatabaseRequestRouterMiddleware (object):

    def process_view( self, request, view_func, args, kwargs ):
        request.META['HOST']

    def process_response( self, request, response ):
        return response


class DatabaseRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return None
```

My problem is my `DatabaseRouter` is not aware of request here how can I pass request into `DatabaseRouter`?

Comment: Search for "multi-tenant django application", that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about specified your db on your queryset, i think it will be more easy to do.

```
#settings.py
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': 'write_db',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
    },
'another_db': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': 'read_db',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
}}

# views.py
def some_views(request):
    if request.META["HOST"] == "www.example.com":
        queryset = YourModels.objects.using("default").all()
    elif request.META["HOST"] == "www.sub.example.com":
        queryset = YourModels.objects.using("another_db").all()

    return
```

## UPDATE

hope it helps you. :)

```
import threading 
from  django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

request_cfg = threading.local()


class RouterMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        url_host = request.META.get("HTTP_HOST")
        if url_host == "www.example.com":
            request_cfg.cfg = "read_db"
        elif url_host == "www.sub.example.com":
            request_cfg.cfg = "default"
        return None

    def process_response(self, request, response ):
        return response


class DatabaseRouter:
    def _default_db(self):
        if hasattr( request_cfg, 'cfg' ):
            return request_cfg.cfg
        else:
            return 'default'

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return self._default_db()


    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return self._default_db()
```

dont forget modified your settings.py:

```
#settings.py

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.DatabaseRouter']

MIDDLEWARE = [...,
              path.to.RouterMiddleware]
```

Comment: sorry I have hundreds of view this was obvious to me too

Comment: Found the same without Mixin good example thanks for your help. Great!